# imagecopyresampled not working not sure why

Tags: php, css, image, jpeg, php-gd

So I'm attempting to use imagecopyresampled to crop out a section of a photo so that I don't have to worry about my users uploading photos larger than intended to my website.  Unfortunately I have yet to figure out why imagecopyresampled is basically behaving as though I simply resized the image using CSS.  From my understanding it should only copy a section of the image at 0,0 based on the coordinates I've provided to a 325X300 px jpg.

!:[example](http://s288.photobucket.com/user/Baalieal/media/imageresampledexample.jpg.html?filters[user]=69801300&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0)

The top image is the one I'm using imagecopyresampled to generate.  My code is as follows.  Just trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here because apparently my copy of GD doesn't have imagecrop otherwise I'd probably be using that.

```
 <html>
 <style>
 .sample{
     width: 325;
     height: 300;
 }
 </style>
 <body>
 <?php
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Image6.jpg');
 $filename = 'Thumbnail_Image6.jpeg';

 $width = 325;
 $height = 300;
 $oldwidth = imagesx($image);
 $oldheight = imagesy($image);
 if( $oldwidth > 325 || $oldheight > 300){
$thumb = ImageCreateTrueColor( 325, 300);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 325, 300, $oldwidth,    $oldheight);
imagejpeg($thumb, $filename, 100);
echo "<img src='".$filename."'><br>";
echo "<img class='sample' src='Image6.jpg'><br>";
 }
 ?>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're going to crop the image, you don't need to use full image size.

```
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 325, 300, 325, 300);
```

Comment: Ah, I thought imagecopyresampled needed the full image size as an argument.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly because your source size is the full size of the source image, so it's resizing it instead of taking a chunk out. Try this to see what I mean:

```
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
```

You can offset the chunk by changing the source `x` and `y` values. Example:

```
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 50, 50, $width, $height, $width, $height);
```